# node.js select data from mysql stack

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i'm new at node.js

trying to slect data from mysql with the following ::

```
 con.query('SELECT * FROM country ',function(err,rows){
    if(err) throw err;
        console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
        console.log(rows);
     });
```

i get the Error from jquert-2.1.4-min.js

```
GET http://localhost:3000/item/create 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

the connection with  data base running ok

```
/**
```

* Created by Hussein on 14/01/2016.
 */

```
function mysql() {
var mysql = require("mysql");
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: "3306",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mydatabase",
});

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');
     //   setTimeout(/*create again */, 2000);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
});

con.end(function (err) {
    // is some thing must be here
});

con.on('close', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        // Oops! Unexpected closing of connection, lets reconnect back.
          con = mysql.createConnection(connection.config);  
    } else {
        console.log('Connection closed normally.');
    }
});
```

}

```
module.exports.con = mysql;
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way to create a DB Connection is

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : MYSQL_DB_HOST,
        user     : MYSQL_DB_USER,
        password : MYSQL_DB_PWD,
        database : MYSQL_DB_NAME
});

con.connect(function(err) {              
    if(err) {                                    
        console.log('con : error when connecting to db : ', err);
        setTimeout(/*create again */, 2000); 
    }
    else {
        console.log('Connected ');
    }                                     
});                                     

con.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('con : db error : ', err);
    if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
        //Create Again                       
    } 
    else {                                    
        throw err;                                  
    }
});
```

Can you please verify, you are creating the connection successfully ?

Comment: the connection is ok for sure because i get with console.log that message
Connected

Comment: are you calling con.end  or conn.destroy  before the result call back hit ?